# How to setCropBox and drawPage will work together in pdf-lib

Tags: pdf-lib.js

I have created a function for crop a pdf page

```
const existingPdfBytes = await fs.promises.readFile('input.pdf');
const existingPdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(existingPdfBytes);
const pdfPage = existingPdfDoc.getPages()[0];
pdfPage.setCropBox(0, 200, 595, 842);
```

Now I want to rotate that cropped pdf and place 5 pdf on single pdf using

```
const rotatedPdfDoc = await PDFDocument.create();
const [embeddedPage] = await rotatedPdfDoc.embedPdf(existingPdfDoc, [0]);
newPage.drawPage(embeddedPage, {
          x: 227,
          y: 421,
          width: 297, 
          height: 297, 
          rotate: degrees(-90),
        });
```

but while embedding getting without cropped data, how can I perform with cropped data

I am using pdf-lib for performing this task, but facing issue to combine both method setCropBox and drawPage both have diffrent data required

Comment: @KJ I understood, it is a cropped viewport
Do you have idea, How can I place that viewport on new page because it is not working with drawPage, for a drawPage I need embedded content

Comment: @KJ Everything I am able to do like 4 PDF pages on a single page with rotation but not able to get cropped area content

Comment: @KJ I am trying to convert cropped PDF as an image, then embed it as an image. Let's see. Becuase someone has done this using pdf-lib (maybe there are some other libraries included ), I am just trying to figure it out

Comment: Hey! were you able to do the cropping? I can't find a way of cropping the pdf.